Booting from encrypted nvme no longer working
I've got a laptop that boots from an encrypted volume group on nvme that was working find. It locked and I had to force power-off and now it won't boot. running 20.04 LTS on an air-gapped computer so I know it didn't apply any updates before the boot.
I look at the boot log and I'm never prompted to type my password to unlock the disk and I drop to initramfs. There's not /dev/nvme* which is why it's not prompting to unlock. If I boot from systemrescue the nvnme devices are there and I can luksMount without issue...filesystem looks good, etc.
